# Dynamically create/limit range for random time and convert to timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have been working on a script that dynamically creates a `date/time` value between two days. However I want to limit it as follows:

- `if appointment.status === "today"`: Set the range between `now` (start) and the `end` of the working day (end) i.e. today between time right now  to `18:00`
- `if appointment.status === "pending"`: Set the range from tomorrow `(start) + 1 week` (end) but keeping in mind the working day `i.e. 08:00-17:00...` so it can be next week `Tuesday 13:00`

Once done, I would like to convert `var date` to a `timestamp.`

This is my code so far:

> ```
> if (appointment.status === "today") {
>   appointment.timestamp = (function() {
>     var a = randomTime(new Date("10-10-2015 10:30"), new Date("12-10-2015 02:10"));
>     return a
>   })();
> } else if (appointment.status === "pending") {
>   appointment.timestamp = (function() {
>     var a = randomTime(new Date("10-10-2015 10:30"), new Date("12-10-2015 02:10"));
>     return a
>   })();
> }
>
> function randomTime(start, end) {
>   var diff = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
>   var new_diff = diff * Math.random();
>   var date = new Date(start.getTime() + new_diff);
>   return date;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date();

if (appointment.status === "today") {
    end.setHours(18);
    end.setMinutes(0);
} else if (appointment.status === "pending") {
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    end.setDate(end.getDate() + 7);
}

start = restrictTimeToWorkHours(start);
end = restrictTimeToWorkHours(end);

appointment.timestamp = Math.floor(randomTime(start, end) / 1000);

function randomTime(start, end) {
    var diff = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
    var new_diff = diff * Math.random();
    return new Date(start.getTime() + new_diff);
}

function restrictTimeToWorkHours(date) {
    if (date.getHours() < 8) {
        date.setHours(8);
        date.setMinutes(0);
    }

    if (date.getHours() > 16) {
        date.setHours(16);
        date.setMinutes(0);
    }

    return date;
}
```

The key thing to remember here is the `Math.floor(randomTime(start, end) / 1000);`. You said you wanted it in timestamp, so I take it to mean you want a Unix Timestamp. A Unix Timestasmp is in seconds, while `Date.getTime()` is in milliseconds, so we need to divide by 1000 to get seconds

Answer (score 1):

Either look for a date library or create your own date transformation function for each operation and combine those.

```
endOfDay(time)
getRandomTimeBetween(startTime, endOfDay(startTime))
isWorkingDay(time)
// etc.
```

For the second case, you can do it in two steps: select a random day in the range, then select a random time within the working hours of that day.

Break it down to simple, logical operations, and you can test each function separately, and your code will look nice and readable.